# Accessing resources located within WEB-INF folder

Tags: java, jsp, maven-war-plugin

I have been working on a simple Java web application which contains JSP files. I have been attempting to access resource files such as, css file and images which resides within the WEB-INF/classes directory through a JSP file which is located in the context root in the resultant WAR file.

The project structure was created based on the recommended structure under [Maven War Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) usages. I went through several solutions provided for similar issues within this forum but none of them worked for this new structure.

How do we access a resource located in WEB-INF/classes directory from a JSP file located in the context-root for example?
[image: example WAR file with the mentioned structure]

Comment: I am not putting them within the WEB-INF, actually if you check the link I have shared on Maven War Plugin usage it packs the images, css files and etc. to the WEB-INF/classes directory. It is the recommended structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to access these resources through HTTP, they *must* be elsewhere - they *can't* be in WEB-INF. That question *would* be a duplicate as it has been answered elsewhere, multiple times (just look up the related questions links for this question). A Java web application will *never* make any resources under WEB-INF accessible through HTTP.

However, as your question is about the "recommended" standard file structure, let me tell you where the documentation you link is misleading: *Any* resources in src/main/resources will end up on the classpath, e.g. in WEB-INF/classes. It will not end up on the directory where the webapplication makes it available to the world. However, the documentation  uses an image, which suggests that the image can be used within the webapplication. It can't. You can access it through the classloader, in your case for example as: `SomeClassFromYourWebapp.class.getResourceAsStream()`. This is more typically done with `.properties` files, `.xml` or similar ones that get processed at runtime than with images. Truly misleading documentation I'd say (but it's correct, just misleading)

Technically this would answer your question for "how do I access the resource from a JSP?", because you can have this code in a JSP. I believe that your question is rather asking to address the resources through HTTP.

And the answer to *that* is: Move the resources that you need available through HTTP to `src/main/webapp` and keep them out of `WEB-INF`. Otherwise they'll only be on the classpath.

Comment: That being say it is  still quite common to put resources in WEB-INF or in classpath  and serve them for http from here. Spring does that for jsp for example.

Comment: @user2189998 for jsp: Yes. However, you can never serve them as /WEB-INF/index.jsp then (as is the point in this answer), but you'll need internal redirection magic. And I've never seen it done for CSS and images, even though it is (theoretically) possible. It's just too much hassle if all you need is a resource with a URL.

Comment: Olaf Kock as you have mentioned it did work when I moved it to src/main/webapp.